# Java8 BufferedReader.lines() stream hangs program compared to imperative solution

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedreader

I'm currently writing a basic webserver in ServerSocket and I'm trying to use java 8 streams to clean up my code. This has been going great but when I try to read in a request using a BufferedReader using a stream, my program hangs and the request is never fully read in. I've listed the differences below.

With Streams:

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
System.out.println("----------REQUEST START---------");
List<String> rawRequest = in.lines()
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .map(line -> line.toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("----------REQUEST END---------\n\n");
```

Without Streams:

```
 InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
 List<String> rawRequest = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

      System.out.println("----------REQUEST START---------");
      // read only headers
      for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null && line.trim().length() > 0; line = in.readLine()) {
        System.out.println(line);
        rawRequest.add(line);
      }
      System.out.println("----------REQUEST END---------\n\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error reading");
      System.exit(1);
    }
```

From what I can tell, these should be roughly equivalent aside from error handling except that in the streams snippet `System.out.println("----------REQUEST END---------\n\n");` is never run.

Comment: this is because lines() never returns, and this is because the socket is still open and thus the reader is trying to read more data (that is, until it hits EOF) before it returns from lines().

Comment: Your own comment 'read only headers' rather gives the game away, don't you think?

Comment: By the way, `map(line -> line.toString())` does absolutely nothing.  You’re converting a String… to a String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not 'roughly equivalent'. Your 'imperative solution' terminates when a blank line is read. The other one terminates only at end of stream, which won't arrive, as the peer is keeping the connection open so as to receive your reply.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you. Is there any way to elegantly "force" the stream to return? My first thought was to check for a blank line and close the buffered reader, but that obviously doesn't work because I need to send output back to the user; or would this be a case where the imperative solution is cleaner due to this implication?

Comment: After combing through the docs I found the proper way to close the input stream without closing the socket (socket.shutdownInput()) and got it to work properly

Comment: @Eric No. You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP, and that's not the way to do it. The length of the incoming request is either contained in the Content-length header or the sum of the chunks. Shutting down the input violates HTTP keepalive.

Comment: @Eric Groom: Java 9 will allow to insert a `.takeWhile(line -> !line.trim().isEmpty())`, but as said by EJP, you shouldn’t try to implement HTTP this way. You can simply use a `URL` object to make the connection; it still allows you to stream over the actual content… There’s also `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` for the server side which is about to become part of the standard in JDK9, but it does already exist in JDK8.

Answer (score -1):

you should check for empty and blank lines something like this

```
in.lines()
.map(line -> line.trim())
.filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
.map(line -> line.toString())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this will skip the blank line

Comment: He doesn't want to skip the blank line. He wants to  *terminate* at the blank line.